# MySQL - Check if two values are equal or both NULL?

Tags: mysql

If I want to compare two values, I can write:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col;
```

I've noticed that this does not work if both `table1.col` and `table2.col` are `NULL`. So my corrected query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON 
  (table1.col = table2.col)
  OR
  (table1.col IS NULL AND table2.col IS NULL);
```

Is this the correct way to compare two values? Is there a way to say two values are equal if they are both `NULL`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comparison `NULL = NULL` will return `NULL`, which is not true so the join won't succeed. You could use the [NULL safe operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) <=>

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.col <=> table2.col;
```

Comment: Awesome. I was not knowing about this operator.